# Adding new content type in opencms

Tags: html, jsp, content-management-system, opencms

I am trying to create new content type option for OPENCMS 9 using HTML code. Could you please suggest/help me to get the solution as how to approach or any predefined documentation is available for the same.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'new content type **option**'? Did you mean a new resource type? A Blog or FAQ Type?

Then look at this:
http://documentation.opencms.org/opencms-documentation/creating-a-website/adding-a-content-type/